# The OnJoinedRoom method is not called when the user joins

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am developing a server using Unity Pun2.

My problem is that the OnJoinedRoom() is not called when the user participates.

There are two cases

1. When making a room and adding it for the first time - called
2. Then, when another party joins the room - not called

   ```
   public override void OnJoinedRoom()
   {

       if (PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount == 1)
       {
           PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("RoomFor1");
       }
   }
   ```

++
my problem is that the master client is called OnJoinedRoom, but the other clients are not called OnJoinedRoom.

Answer (score 1):

use OnPlayerEnteredRoom() to check if **another** player entered the room you are in

use OnJoinedRoom() to check if you yourself have successfully joined a room

Comment: Hello Thank you for answer

I know that OnPlayerEnteredRoom () is called, which other participants add to the room

However, my problem is that the master client is called OnJoinedRoom, but the other clients are not called OnJoinedRoom.

Answer (score -1):

This happens when you are calling another scene with another script, so it will exit from the given script which is waiting for joining.