# Perform operation when a player enters the room

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I want to create a multiplayer application using Photon (Pun2). After a player joins the room, I want to hide some buttons and display others for all the players in that room. At the moment I have this function:

```
public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
     {
         print(newPlayer); // #02
         if (PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount == 2 && PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
         {
             print(PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount + "/2 Starting game...");
 
             searchingBtn.SetActive(false); // hide this button
             findMatchBtn.SetActive(false); // hide this button
             scanningBtn.SetActive(true); // display this button
         }
     }
```

But this won't work, because only for 1 of the 2 players the buttons will change, for the other one they will stay the same.

I saw some examples on the Internet, where in this function `OnPlayerEnteredRoom` it's called `PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(scene_index)`, but at that moment, I don't want to load another scene, I want to stay in the current scene and just hide/display some buttons. Is this even possible?

**EDIT: Here is the final version**

```
public override void OnJoinedRoom()
{
    Debug.Log("You joined the room.");
    Debug.Log(PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount);
    Debug.Log(PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient);

    UpdateButtons();
}

public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
{
    Debug.Log("Other players joined the room.");
    if (PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount > 1 && PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
    {
        Debug.Log(PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount + "/2 Starting game...");

        UpdateButtons();
    }
}

private void UpdateButtons()
{
    searchingBtn.SetActive(false); // hide this button
    findMatchBtn.SetActive(false); // hide this button
    scanningBtn.SetActive(true); // display this button
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The OnJoinedRoom method is not called when the user joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56206040/the-onjoinedroom-method-is-not-called-when-the-user-joins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Photon Documentation:

```
virtual void OnJoinedRoom ()
    //Called when the LoadBalancingClient entered a room, no matter if this client 
    //created it or simply joined.
```

```
virtual void OnPlayerEnteredRoom (Player newPlayer)
    //Called when a remote player entered the room. This Player is already added to 
    //the playerlist.
```

With this knowledge, `OnPlayerEnteredRoom` is only called when a remote player joins the room. So in order to solve your problem, you'll need to call your code in the `OnJoinedRoom` callback for the local client and `OnPlayerEnteredRoom` when a remote player joins.

In summary, your new code should look like this:

```
public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
{
     UpdateButtons(newPlayer);
}

public override void OnJoinedRoom(Player player)
{
    UpdateButtons(player);
}

private void UpdateButtons(Player player)
{
    if (PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount > 1 && PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
    {             
        print(PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount + "/2 Starting game...");
 
        searchingBtn.SetActive(false); // hide this button
        findMatchBtn.SetActive(false); // hide this button
        scanningBtn.SetActive(true); // display this button
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! But the override function `OnJoinedRoom` does not recieve any parameter, so this won't work.

Comment: But I understand your point, I edited my post with the final version. thanks a lot for this!

Comment: @Tenzolinho Oh, my mistake. Just use `PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer` to get a reference to yourself. If that is what you are looking for.